# I am getting $1 = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a Question (although it is a geometry question, I am just putting the part where I am stuck) where:
$$6 = \sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2} = \sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}$$

And I have to find the value of $x$ and $y$. Now I know that I can solve: $$6 = \sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2}$$ and upon doing just that I find:$$x^2+y^2+6x=27 \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Now I can also solve: $$6 = \sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}$$
By doing that I find: $$x^2+y^2-6x=27\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Now I can subtract equation 1 from equation 2 from which I get :
$$x = 0$$
Now I can just put the value of $x$ in either equation 1 or equation 2 to find the value of $y$,which comes out to be $$y = \pm \sqrt{27}$$

But what I am actually stuck on is when I try to solve:$$\sqrt{(x+3)^2+y^2} = \sqrt{(x-3)^2+y^2}$$
$$(x+3)^2+y^2 = (x-3)^2+y^2$$
$$(x+3)^2=(x-3)^2$$
$$x^2+9+6x = x^2+9-6x$$
$$6x = -6x$$
$$1=-1$$
Now I don't know what I did wrong here and that's why I am asking here.
As always any help to point my dumb a** in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Asked thousands of times..

Comment: You got $x=0$ and later you divided by $6x$. Do you see the problem with this ?

Comment: The second-to-last equation $6x = -6x$ does not imply $-1 = 1$, it implies $12x = 0$ and therefore $x = 0$. (Presumably the $x$ got canceled; that's not a valid deduction unless $x \neq 0$.)